# Qemu config file error "Invalid parameter host"

Tags: linux, configuration, kvm, qemu

I'm new to QEMU and currently playing around with QEMU config file to understand how it works. I tried to put all the options of my simple QEMU command line

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -enable-kvm -m 8192 -nic user,host=192.168.0.2,net=192.168.0.2 -nic bridge,br=virbr0 ubuntu.img
```

in the config file `qemu.cfg` and here is how it looks like:

```
[nic "user"]
host=192.168.0.2
net=192.168.0.2
[nic "bridge"]
br=virbr0 


cpu = host
enable-kvm
m = 8192
ubuntu.img
```

Running QEMU with the `readconfig` file specified I got the following error

```
$ sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -readconfig qemu.cfg 
qemu-system-x86_64:qemu.cfg:1: Invalid parameter 'host=192.168.0.2'
```

How to fix the configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of googling I didn't find any comprehensive manual related to the syntax of the configuration file. So I looked at the source code and here is the resulting config file:

```
[nic]
type = "user"
host = "192.168.0.2"
net = "192.168.0.2"

[nic]
type = "bridge"
br = "virbr0"

[memory]
size = "8192"
```

There are some mistakes made in the config presented in the question:

1. **Spaces matter**

It is required to insert space before and after the `"="` sign:

```
   [nic]
   type = "user" #correct

   [nic]
   type="user" #wrong
```

2. **Find a correct name of a config group.**

In case of incorrectly named config group qemu prints error message of the form:

```
There is no option group
```

It's easy to find it in the [qemu source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/qemu/latest/source/util/qemu-config.c#L24). After that we just need to find all the config groups added into

```
static QemuOptsList *vm_config_groups[48];
```

The function [`void qemu_add_opts(QemuOptsList *list)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/qemu/latest/source/util/qemu-config.c#L294) is responsible for that. The parameters for `nic` group can be found in the [declaration](https://elixir.bootlin.com/qemu/latest/source/net/net.c#L1623):

```
QemuOptsList qemu_nic_opts = {
    .name = "nic",
    .implied_opt_name = "type",
    .head = QTAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(qemu_nic_opts.head),
    .desc = {
        /*
         * no elements => accept any params
         * validation will happen later
         */
        { /* end of list */ }
    },
};
```

which implies the syntax I specified in the answer.

**Unanswered question**:

I don't know if there's a way to specify the rest of the options`-cpu host -enable-kvm ubuntu.img` via such configuration file. Looking through the valid groups didn't yield any useful results.

**UPD**:

It turned out that `-enable-kvm` is being configured through the [`accel`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/qemu/latest/source/softmmu/vl.c#L253) option group as follows:

```
[accel]
accel = "kvm"
```